# Using add_sub_menu to put into Appearance Section

Tags: plugin-development

I am working on a new plugin, and want to add my plugin menu to the Themes/Appearances section.

```
add_submenu_page('themes.php','Widget Area Manager','administrator','widget_area_manager','wm_area_manager_admin');
```

However the menu get's added to the setting's section of the dashboard.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function widget_area_mamanger(){
    add_theme_page( 'Widget Area Manager', 'Widget Area Manager', 'administrator', 'widget_area_manager', 'wm_area_manager_admin' );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'widget_area_mamanger');
```